# How to pass alphanumeric value in cloud formation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want add tags to ec2 machine created via cloud formation template. my tag values are alphanumeric. what should be the type:

```
Parameters:
  environment:
    Type: String
    Default: "prod1-xyz2345"
  EC2Instance: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      Tags:
      - Key: environment
        Value:
          Ref: environment
```

Here Type: String throws error since value of tag is alphanumeric (prod1-xyz2345). What should be the type here ??

Comment: What is the actual error?  Per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) a `String` type shouldn't have any issues with a value like `"prod1-xyz23456"`.

Comment: Thank you. The issue was with  Ref: environment_1 . my Ref value was having underscores and alphanumeric.